# Limit with fractional part

Tags: calculus, limits

Find $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin\{x\}}{\{x\}}$$ where $\{x\}=$ fractional part $=x-[x] $.

Please help me to solve. I know the defn of $[x] $ and $\lim_{x\to 0-}[x]=-1$ and $\lim_{x\to 0+}[x]=0$.

Comment: Show that the left side limit is $\sin(1)$, but the right side limit is $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that $\{x\}=$ fractional part of $x$ $=x-[x] \ge 0$ $\forall$ $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

So L.H.L.$=\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{\sin\{x\}}{\{x\}}=\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{\sin (1+x)}{(1+x)}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin (1-x)}{(1-x)}=\sin 1$

and R.H.L.$=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin\{x\}}{\{x\}}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$

So limit does not exist as L.H.L.$\not =$R.H.L.

Comment: $$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{\sin\{x\}}{\{x\}}=\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{\sin (x-1)}{(x-1)}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin (0-1)}{(0-1)}=\sin 1$$ Is this not correct?

Comment: @user1942348 No, it will be $$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{\sin\{x\}}{\{x\}}=\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{\sin (1+x)}{(1+x)}=\lim_{x\to 0^{+}}\frac{\sin (1-x)}{(1-x)}$$ since as $x\to 0^{-}$ , $\{x\}=x-[x]=x-(-1)=1+x$ and when we change it to $x\to 0^{+}$, we can change $1+x$ to $1-x$.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Ok. Then what is the necessity to change to x→0+, by changing 1+x to 1−x. Why not you simply write 
$$\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{\sin (x+1)}{(x+1)}=\lim_{x\to 0^{-}}\frac{\sin (0+1)}{(0+1)}=\sin 1$$

Comment: @user1942348 No need to change if you don't like it. I did it for my own simplicity. You can skip that step if you like. BTW you once again wrote the wrong equation (the leftmost term...it will be $1+x$, not $x-1$).

Comment: yes, i have edited